# google analytics not tracking all the form submissions

Tags: forms, function, events, google-analytics, submission

I have a problem with the tracking of my forms, I want to use ga script, example: ga('send, event, Category, Action, Label); I try this in many ways, and currently I tried to use this script in the sucess function that I have, I thought that, when the success message of sweetalert fires, the event fires as well.. This is currently working, I tested many times, but I'm not having an even number between  the numbers in ga, and in another platform that I use, one counts 37 submited forms, and the other 77. Does anyone know if the Google analytics script is not firing sometimes or there is another issue?

The function that I use is an onClick one, in GA they tell to use like `onclick="ga('send, event, Category, Action, Label);"`, but by having the function for the success or error I had to adapt..

Comment: You need to provide a little more of code or example. If the form has an action and you reload the page or goes to another, if Google Analytics is not so fast enough to send the hit you acurracy will be reduced. In other case can be issue with the validation. In definition is common have a Gap, round 5% to 15% depending the way you implemented,  but in your case is so high.  What i can suggest you is use timestamp +  math.random on  the label and add that parameter too in you database, in that way you can isolate the Errors and start debugging, but here now we need more information.

Comment: Also i forgot to say welcome to StackOver Flow and remmember to look the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask